# List View text color is not changed Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to change the listview text color but its not changing. Also i have used different list style but the color of Text in the list is not changing. Help me to solve this problem
This is the code

```
 public class Line extends Activity
 {

List<Map<String, String>> data;

Map<String, String> Line1;
Map<String, String> Line2;

ListView Lines = null;

public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    Lines = new ListView(Line.this);
    Lines = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    Line1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Line1.put("title", "Row | 1" );
    Line1.put("status", "");
    data.add(Line1);

   Line2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Line2.put("title", "Row | 2" );
    Line2.put("status", "");
    data.add(Line2);


    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    Lines.setAdapter(adapter);


void SetStatus(int nLineNo, String sStatusMsg)
{
    if(nLineNo == 0)
    {
        Line1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Line1.put("title", "Line | 1" );
        Line1.put("status", sStatusMsg);
        data.set(0, Line1);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

        Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    if(nLineNo == 1)
    {
        Line2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Line2.put("title", "Line | 2" );
        Line2.put("status", sStatusMsg);
        data.set(1, Line2);
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

        Lines.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    }
```

xml of listview

```
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="338dp"
            android:padding="10dip" 
            android:listSelector="#372f89"
            style="@drawable/liststyle"
             android:textColor="@color/tabDark"
              android:background="#fcfbdf" 
            android:scrollbars="none" 
            android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff">

            <!-- Preview: listitem=@android:layout/simple_list_item_2 -->

        </ListView>

</TableRow>
```

list style xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/circlebtn"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Go with `Custom Adapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` which uses default `simple_list_item_2` for ListView row.

Pass `list style xml`(assuming created by you) to `SimpleAdapter` :

```
   SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data,  
        R.layout.<list style xml>, new String[] {"title", "status"}, 
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
```

Comment: @user3835770: show your updated code what you are passing here `R.layout.<list style xml>` ?

Comment: SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"title", "status"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="@style/GreenText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"

        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

Comment: <style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>

Comment: @user3835770: what is name of `<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" style="@style/GreenText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />` layout ?

Comment: @user3835770: use that layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` like `R.layout.custom_layout_file_name_which_is_created_by_you`

Comment: @user3835770: what is name of `<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" style="@style/GreenText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />` layout ?

Comment: @user3835770: create a xml file in layout folder with name of "custom_row_layout" and paste `<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" style="@style/GreenText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />` code in it and pass `R.layout.custom_row_layout` in `SimpleAdapter adapter

Comment: custom_row_layout is not accessing from the layout folder. giving the same error custom_layout cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @user3835770: man  create a xml file in layout folder with name of "custom_row_layout" and paste `<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" style="@style/GreenText" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:paddingLeft="6dip" android:paddingRight="10dip" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />` code in it and pass `R.layout.custom_row_layout` in `SimpleAdapter adapter